# How can I get the handle of the IE tab that has focus?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Does anyone know of a way to get the handle of the IE tab that has current focus using vbscript?

I'm trying to do some Automation using HP-UFT and need to get the handle of the tab that has focus so I can close it.

UFT treats each tab as it's own separate browser, so I'm able to get the collection of tabs but I have not been able to find a way to determine which one has the current focus.

The browser I am using is IE.

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Sorry @ManishChristian, I'm using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer will work only for IE.

You do not need to get handle of particular tab. Just run a loop on number of opened tabs and check if it's visible or not. Delete if it's visible.

Here is working sample code:

```
iTab = Browser("CreationTime:=0").GetROProperty("number of tabs")
For i = 0 To iTab - 1
    If Browser("CreationTime:=" & i).GetROProperty("visible") Then
        Print "Closing : " & Browser("CreationTime:=" & i).GetROProperty("name")
        Browser("CreationTime:=" & i).Close
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

This will close current focused tab.

Comment: Brilliant idea using the Visible property. Seems to be working! Cheers!